# How can we use external Js file using script tag in react hook?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I have created a Component named ObjektlistPreview. This component will show the data inside div. And the data is being fetch by Js File, which is in script tag.

I have tried using Helmet and useEffect but always error gives in console
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'MyObjektlist' has already been declared.**
MyObjektlist is the class in Js file.

Js File:

```
 class MyObjektlist {

    constructor () {
      this.container;
      this.script_container;
   }

init(){
    this.container = document.getElementById('ex-container');
    var sc = document.createElement('div');
    sc.id = 'ex-script-container'; 

 and so on.....
```

Here is my component code:

Using Helmet:

```
   import Helmet from "react-helmet";

   const ObjektlistPreview = (props) => {

return(
    <div className="bg-grey p-3 mb-3" id="objContainer">
        <h1>Preview { props.id } {props.userId} </h1>
        <div id="ex-container" data-id='10234'></div>
         <Helmet>   
            <script src="https://example.com/js/objektlist_test.js" type="text/javascript" />
        </Helmet>
    </div>

);
```

}

Using useEffect:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Helmet from "react-helmet";

const ObjektlistPreview = (props) => {


useEffect(() => {
     const script = document.createElement('script');
     script.src = "https://example.com/js/objektlist_test.js";
     script.async = true;
     document.querySelector("#objContainer").appendChild(script);
     return () => {
         if(document.querySelector("#objContainer"))
             document.querySelector("#objContainer").removeChild(script);
         } 
   }, []);

return(
    <div className="bg-grey p-3 mb-3" id="objContainer">
        <h1>Preview { props.id } {props.userId} </h1>
        <div id="ex-container" data-id='10529'></div>
         
    </div>

);
```

}

Please suggest me where is the Problem. Or there is another way to use this external js file in React hook. Server side i am using node Js.

Comment: Removing script won't remove variables that the script created